# customize choosing a tag feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

So I have an app user can create a tag, and choose a tag to post their stories. Everything works fine, but I want to change the way user choosing a tag to post stories. Right now, user has to scroll through the tag they want(more tags created, more scrolls user has to do)[image]

What I'm trying to do is to display, some main tags I make to be inside box and user to be able click the tag that the tag to be chosen. It would be nice to make a search engine that user can type and the tag to be shown up that user can pick....but this seems too advanced for me now. (if you know how, please let me know)

[image]

the above is what I hope mine to be replaced to.

I'm not even sure which code I should touch to make this happen.
views.py?forms.py? or is this javascript?html file?

Comment: I am not a javascript expert, but I think you should write js code in the page (i.e. include it in the template) that on input events issues queries to the back-end to search for tags of the given prefix (for example). If your back-end offers a RESTful API things get easy. Look into [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Comment: @Pynchia hmm this also sounds too advance for me, I was hoping there's 3rd party app for this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching for [Select2](https://select2.github.io/), there is a django package called [django-select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2)

Comment: wow thanks man, I was looking over haystack but select2 fits more into what I'm looking for. Is it possible to display some of main tags in the box like reddit example above?

Comment: @kimkimm, I think that what you want to do isn't the best variant also, imagine you have thousands of tags, you page will became very messy. Reddit offers box with user subreddits but not all subreddits as there are so many of them, Reddit allows you to search for all subreddits with entering some text into it. Speaking of Select2 there is what you can use: [tags](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags)

Comment: oh I meant like offering box that only contains the tags I will be making, not all of them ofc :)

Comment: hmm I'm looking over it right now, it seems like it doesn't have that feature, do you know how by anychance?

Comment: @kimkimm, what do you mean by "that only contains the tags I will be making, not all of them"?

Comment: I will be making the tags as well through django-admin, and I want them to be displayed in the main section when user picks tag

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10819135)

Comment: instead of "your subscribed subreddits", I want the tags I made them to be displayed in a box

Comment: @Serjik, this is the original question I asked, read the above before you critique

Comment: @Serjik, do you know the solution to my problem?is that why you commented asking to make a new thread?

Comment: @kimkimm, yeah, but that's what I wanted to say, are you sure that you page won't be too messy, when the amount of your tags increase? Reddit uses box with user's subreddits and input box for all subreddits. Speaking of searching within all tags, `select2` will be nice, and when you want to create a simple box with to pick from I am not sure that there are any 3rd party apps as this can be done in 30 lines of JQuery

Comment: @pythad I won't have too many tags. Oh I'm learning JQuery right now actually(watching tutorials) do you know where to find that 30 lines of JQuery? is it from JQuery library?

Comment: @kimkimm, I suggest you continue learning JQuery, after a few tutorials you will get the idea of how to do this, if you have any problems ask them at SO with `js` tag, someone will definitely help you. JQuery is a library for more simple interactions with HTML, it doesn't provide snippets like that.

Comment: ok, at least I know which tool to use it for that. thanks man